# Как удалить библиотеки из списка доступных библиотек Office?

Tags: vba, com, office

В VBA есть раздел Reference, где отображается список доступных для подключения библиотек.

Как можно сделать, что бы в этом списке не отображались некоторые библиотеки?(Т.е удалить их вообще оттуда)

Comment: Ну разве что удалить компонент из системы... а какова цель этого странного мероприятия?

Comment: а, зачем, собственно говоря?

Comment: А у меня от .NET осталось много тестовых библиотек для офиса=>отображаются либы, которых физически нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел программу RegDLLView, которая позволяет найти либы, которые не имеют физического файла, а затем их можно удалить, что бы они нигде не отображались.

Можно так же руками из реестра удалить узлы, которые ссылаются на либу в ветке:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{YOUR-CLSID}
```